# Bad readable state with nanomsg surveyor socket

Tags: nanomsg

I am using the SURVEY scalability protocol with nanomsg in Python.

I have a bunch of respondent sockets, I connect a surveyor to them
in a loop; then, **I wait for *surveyor.send_fd* to be readable. I assume it is connected to at least one respondent**,
then I send the survey.
On the respondent side, I wait for *respondent.recv_fd* to be readable, and I call `respondent.recv()` to know about the
survey, then I send the answer.
Back to the surveyor, I wait for *surveyor.recv_fd* to be
readable and I call  `surveyor.recv()` to get answers from respondents.

Sometimes I get an error when trying to read answers from respondents:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    [...]
nanomsg.NanoMsgAPIError: Operation cannot be performed in this state
```

I simplify the code to show the issue:

#### test_respondent.py

```
import nanomsg
import select
resp = nanomsg.Socket(nanomsg.RESPONDENT)
resp.bind("tcp://*:6542")
print 'waiting for respondent to be readable'
select.select([resp.recv_fd],[],[])
print 'receiving survey'
print resp.recv(flags=nanomsg.DONTWAIT)
print 'sending reply to surveyor'
resp.send("reply")
```

#### test_surveyor.py

```
import select
import nanomsg
s = nanomsg.Socket(nanomsg.SURVEYOR)
s.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:6542")
print 'waiting for surveyor to be connected'
select.select([s.send_fd],[],[])
s.send("hello", nanomsg.DONTWAIT)
print "waiting for surveyor to be readable"
select.select([s.recv_fd],[],[])
print 'receiving reply from respondent'
print s.recv(flags=nanomsg.DONTWAIT)
```

#### test.sh

```
python test_respondent.py &
python test_surveyor.py
```

Executing the test several times should lead to the exception described
above in some cases.

Any idea what I am doing wrong ? And how to fix the problem ?

Comment: There is an answer for a similar question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071644/surveyor-respondent-patter-in-nanomsg-in-python/31072730#31072730

Comment: thanks! In fact, the bug is supposed to be fixed... Look at the discussion in github issue #414 and commit: https://github.com/nanomsg/nanomsg/commit/e2811f22afa1cc68b79bab82c8e66b36823e48be